# org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException when trying to create repository instance

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I get a mappingException when i run the spring application and its trying to create an instance of a repository i created.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-04-22 15:58:36.624 ERROR 23606 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:156) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.zawn.RestmongoApplication.main(RestmongoApplication.java:19) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[restmongo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[restmongo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) ~[restmongo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) ~[restmongo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:88) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:438) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:191) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtRequestFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jwtUserDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtUserDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usersRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class java.lang.Object!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:211) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:169) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:154) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:253) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:227) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:53) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:467) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar!/:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:107) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtUserDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usersRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class java.lang.Object!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usersRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class java.lang.Object!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 75 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class java.lang.Object!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.MappingContext.getRequiredPersistentEntity(MappingContext.java:79) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:150) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:124) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:312) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:212) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.java:119) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.4.RELEASE]
```

```
package com.zawn.repository;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Example;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.querydsl.QuerydslPredicateExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.data.mapping.context.MappingContext;
import com.zawn.domain.Users;
import com.zawn.domain.preview.UsersPreview;
import com.zawn.repository.repofrag.UsersRepoFragment;

@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = UsersPreview.class)
@Repository
public interface UsersRepository<Users, String> extends MongoRepository<Users, String> {

    @Query("{ username: ?0 }")
    Optional<Users> findByUsername(String username);

}
```

```
package com.zawn.domain;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.Indexed;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.DBRef;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

/**
 * Users
 * <p>
 *
 *
 */
@Document(collection="users")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({"username", "password", "type", "idcompany", "hidden", "status", "verified", "notes", "logs"})  
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Users extends AbstractLoggedDocument {
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    @NotEmpty
    @JsonProperty("username")
    private String username=null;
    @NotEmpty
    @JsonProperty("password")
    public String password=null;
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("type")
    public Type type=null;
    @JsonProperty("idcompany")
    @Valid
    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    public Users idcompany =null ;

    @JsonProperty("hidden")
    public Boolean hidden=null;
    @JsonProperty("status")
    public StatusEnum status=null;
    @JsonProperty("verified")
    public Boolean verified=null;
    @JsonProperty("notes")
    public String notes=null;

    @JsonProperty("Id")
    public String id=null;


    public String getId() {
        return this.id.toString();
    }
    public enum Type {
        OPERATOR("OPERATOR"), ADMIN("ADMIN"), COMPANY("COMPANY"), PERSON("PERSON"),PARTNER("PARTNER");
        private final String value;
        private final static Map<String, Users.Type> CONSTANTS = new HashMap<>();

        static {
            for (Users.Type c : values()) {
                CONSTANTS.put(c.value, c);
            }
        }

        private Type(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.value;
        }

        @JsonValue
        public String value() {
            return this.value;
        }

        @JsonCreator
        public static Users.Type fromValue(String value) {
            Users.Type constant = CONSTANTS.get(value);
            if (constant == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(value);
            } else {
                return constant;
            }
        }

    }
    public Type getType() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.type;
    }
    public void setPassword(String pwd) {
        this.password = pwd;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String usrname) {
        this.username = usrname;
    }
    public Boolean getHidden() {
        return this.hidden;
    }
    public void setHidden(Boolean hidden) {
        this.hidden = hidden;
    }
    public StatusEnum getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }
    public void setStatus(StatusEnum status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public void setVerified(Boolean verified) {
        this.verified = verified;
    }
    public void setNotes(String notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }
    public void setType(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public Boolean getVerified() {
        return this.verified;
    }


}
```

```
package com.zawn.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigInteger;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class AbstractDocument implements Serializable {
    @Id
    protected String id=null;

    String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

}
```

```
package com.zawn.conf;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoClientConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.CustomConversions;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;

@Configuration
//@EnableMongoRepositories("com.zawn.repository")
public class MongoClientConfiguration extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration  {
    @Autowired
    private List<Converter<?, ?>> converters;


    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "zwrt";
    }

    @Override
    public com.mongodb.client.MongoClient mongoClient() {
        //return MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:27017/?replicaSet=rs0&w=majority");

        return MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    }

//  @Override
//  public String getMappingBasePackage() {
//      return "com.zawn.domain";
//    }

    @Override
    public CustomConversions customConversions() {
        return new CustomConversions(converters);
    }

}
```

```
package com.zawn.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.zawn.domain.Users;
import com.zawn.dto.UserDTO;
import com.zawn.repository.UsersRepository;

@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository<Users, String> userDao;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder bcryptEncoder;

    public Users insert(UserDTO user) {
        Authentication userAuthen=SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if(user.getType()==Users.Type.ADMIN) {
            if(userAuthen==null || userAuthen.getAuthorities()==null || 
                    !userAuthen.getAuthorities().contains(UserRole.AUTHORITY_ADMIN))
                throw new AccessDeniedException("Only a user of type 'ADMIN' permitted to create 'ADMIN'.");
        }
        Users newUser = new Users();
        copyTo(newUser, user, true, false);
        return userDao.insert(newUser);
    }

    /**
     * Update all field except password. 
     * @param user
     * @return
     */
    public Users update(UserDTO user, boolean patch) {
        Users updatedUser = userDao.findById(user.getId()).orElseThrow(
                () -> new UserNotFoundException(user.getId().toString()));
        // Authorisation
        Authentication userAuthen=SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if(!patch || patch && user.getType()!=null)
        if(user.getType()==Users.Type.ADMIN || updatedUser.getType() == Users.Type.ADMIN ) {
            if(userAuthen==null || userAuthen.getAuthorities()==null || 
                    !userAuthen.getAuthorities().contains(UserRole.AUTHORITY_ADMIN))
                throw new AccessDeniedException("Only a user of type 'ADMIN' permitted to update 'ADMIN' user.");
        }
        copyTo(updatedUser, user, false, patch);
        return userDao.save(updatedUser);
    }

    public Users resetPassword(UserDTO user) {
        if(user.getPassword()==null) throw new NotSetPasswordException();
        Users updatedUser = userDao.findById(user.getId()).orElseThrow(
                () -> new UserNotFoundException(user.getId().toString()));
        updatedUser.setPassword(bcryptEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        return userDao.save(updatedUser);
    }

    public void delete(UserDTO user) {
        Users updatedUser = userDao.findById(user.getId()).orElseThrow(
                () -> new UserNotFoundException(user.getId().toString()));

            // Authorisation
            Authentication userAuthen=SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            if(updatedUser.getType()==Users.Type.ADMIN ) {
                if(userAuthen==null || userAuthen.getAuthorities()==null || 
                        !userAuthen.getAuthorities().contains(UserRole.AUTHORITY_ADMIN))
                    throw new AccessDeniedException("Only a user of type 'ADMIN' permitted to delete 'ADMIN' user.");
            }
            userDao.delete(updatedUser);    
    }

    private void copyTo(Users updatedUser, UserDTO user, boolean resetPassword, boolean patch) {
        if(resetPassword)
            updatedUser.setPassword(bcryptEncoder.encode(user.getPassword())); 
        if(!patch || patch && user.getHidden()!=null)
        updatedUser.setHidden(user.getHidden());
        if(!patch || patch && user.getUsername()!=null)
        updatedUser.setUsername(user.getUsername());
        if(!patch || patch && user.getType()!=null)
        updatedUser.setType(user.getType());
        if(!patch || patch && user.getStatus()!=null)
        updatedUser.setStatus(user.getStatus());
        if(!patch || patch && user.getNotes()!=null)
        updatedUser.setNotes(user.getNotes());
        if(!patch || patch && user.getVerified()!=null)
        updatedUser.setVerified(user.getVerified());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Users class is subclassed by another class abstract document.
Neither Users or abstractdocment had a filed declarde with the @Id annotation, which resulted in the mapping exception.